# Troubleshooting java script maximum / minimium / average / barchart code 2 classes 4 function methods

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, error-correction

My goal is to have it output the min max avg and a barchart.

`

```
package arraystuff1;
    import java.util.Random;
    public class problem1 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int min=0;
        int max=0;
        int avg=0;
        //initialize array
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        final int Length = 30;
        int[] array1 = new int[Length];
        for ( int counter = 0; counter < array1.length; counter++ )
        {
        array1[ counter ] = 1+randomNumbers.nextInt( 100 );
        }
        //array tested and produces correct output
        for ( int counter = 0; counter < array1.length; counter++ )//minimum
        {
                 min = functionsp1.min(array1[counter],min);
                 if(counter == Length-1)
                     System.out.printf("The minimum value is: %d\n",min);
         
        }
        for ( int counter = 0; counter < array1.length; counter++ )//maximum
        {
                 max = functionsp1.max(array1[counter],max);
                 if(counter == Length-1)
                     System.out.printf("The maximum value is: %d\n",max);
         
        }
        for ( int counter = 0; counter < array1.length; counter++ )//average
        {
                 avg = functionsp1.avg(array1[counter],Length);
                 if(counter == Length-1)
                     System.out.printf("The average value is: %d\n",avg);
         
        }
        for ( int counter = 0; counter < array1.length; counter++ )//average
        {
                functionsp1.bar(array1[counter],Length);//print a line showing range of the bar graph  use switch case to build frequencies for each 10th unit
                functionsp1.freq(array1[counter],Length);//print stars representing number of random numbers that fit in this category
                     
         
        }
        
        
            
    }
}
```

`
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

`

```
package arraystuff1;
public class functionsp1 
{
    public static int min(int counter,int min)//input array index and length
    {
        if (counter < min)
        {
            counter = min;
        }
        return counter;
    }
    public static int max(int counter,int max)
    {
        if (counter > max)
        {
            counter = max;
        }
        return counter;
    }
    public static int avg(int current,int total)//input array length for total and index for current
    {
        int sum;
        int fintotal;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < total; counter++ )
            {
            sum = current + sum; // random number 0-99 add 1 to make it 1-100
            if (counter == total)
                fintotal = sum/total;
            return fintotal;
            }
            System.out.printf("The average of the array is: %2d",fintotal);
            //System.out.printf( "%s%8s\n", "Index", "Value" ); // column headings
    return fintotal;
    }
    public static void bar(int index,int limit)//length and array variable
    {
        System.out.println("Grade Distribution:  ");
        for(int counter = 0; counter < limit;counter++)
        {
            if (counter ==10)
                System.out.printf("%5d: ", 100);
            else
                System.out.printf("%02d-%02d: ",counter*10,counter*10+9);
        }   
    }   
    public static void freq( int stars )
   {
      for(int counter=0;counter<stars ; counter ++)
               System.out.print("*");
   } // end main
}
```

`

I have verified the array initialized with 30 random numbers in the range of 1-100. My goal is to get the bar chart and the other functions to work but this is the first time I have played with an array any suggestions?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let your Functionsp1 class methods deal with the Array for example:

```
//initialize array
java.util.Random randomNumbers = new java.util.Random();
final int length = 30;
int[] array1 = new int[length];
for (int counter = 0; counter < array1.length; counter++) {
    array1[counter] = randomNumbers.nextInt(100) + 1;
}
//array tested and produces correct output
    
Functionsp1 fnctn = new Functionsp1();
int min = fnctn.min(array1);
int max = fnctn.max(array1);
int avg = fnctn.avg(array1);
System.out.printf("The minimum value in array1 is: %d%n", min);
System.out.printf("The maximum value in array1 is: %d\n", max);
System.out.printf("The average value in array1 is: %d\n", avg);
System.out.println("Horizontal Graph For Numerical Range: " + min + " To " + max);
fnctn.bar(array1);

public class Functionsp1 {

    public int min(int[] array) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < min) {
                min = array[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public int max(int[] array) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > max) {
                max = array[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public int avg(int[] array) {
        int avg = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : array) {
            sum += i;
        }
        avg = sum / array.length;
        return avg;
    }

    public void bar(int[] array) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Grade Distribution:");
        System.out.println("0 0         10        20        30        40        50"
                + "        60        70        80        90        100");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i]; j++) {
                if ((counter + 1) % 10 == 0) {
                    sb.append("+");
                }
                else {
                    sb.append("|");
                }
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.printf("%-3s%-103s(%-3s)%n", (i+1), sb.toString(), array[i]);
            sb.setLength(0);
            //System.out.printf("%-3s%-100s%n", (i + 1), String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(array[i], "|")));
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    public void freq(int stars) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < stars; counter++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}
```

I still can't figure out what the `freq()` method is suppose to accomplish.

As the code above stands right now, if run will produce something like the following in the Console Window:

```
The minimum value in array1 is: 1
The maximum value in array1 is: 99
The average value in array1 is: 55
Horizontal Graph For Numerical Range: 1 To 99

Grade Distribution:
0 0         10        20        30        40        50        60        70        80        90        100
1  |||||||||+||||                                                                                         (14 )
2  |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||                                                (55 )
3  |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+             (90 )
4  |||||                                                                                                  (5  )
5  |||||||||+                                                                                             (10 )
6  |||||||||+|||||||||+||||||||                                                                           (28 )
7  |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+||||         (94 )
8  |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||                                                                            (27 )
9  |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|            (91 )
10 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||                                                                          (29 )
11 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||                                                      (49 )
12 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+||                                                             (42 )
13 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||      (97 )
14 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+||||         (94 )
15 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||    (99 )
16 |                                                                                                      (1  )
17 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||                        (79 )
18 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||        (95 )
19 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+                                           (60 )
20 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|                                                              (41 )
21 |||||||||+|||                                                                                          (13 )
22 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+||                               (72 )
23 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||                              (73 )
24 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||                                                                            (27 )
25 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+                       (80 )
26 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+||                     (82 )
27 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+||||                                                                     (34 )
28 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+||||||||     (98 )
29 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+                                                                         (30 )
30 |||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+|||||||||+||||                                                 (54 )
```